# Java.Lang.NullPointerException In Xamarin.Android Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I encountered a problem when writing a project on Xamarin.Android (Visual Studio 2017)

When I start my project, this error "Java.Lang.NullPointerException" appears to me

This error appears on "SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main)"

But "activity_main" has no problem...

Comment: Please post your activity_main layout file and the .cs code that calls SetContentView (e.g., your OnCreate() method) so we can take a look to see what the issue might be.

Comment: Open your project, please delete `bin` and `obj` folder, then re-build your project